# Создание и вывод картинки

Tags: php

Данный код находится в img.php

```
    <?php
    $a=rand(0,9);
    $b=rand(1,9);
    $c=$a+$b;
    $text=''.$a.'+'.$b.'=';
    $im = imagecreate(100, 30);
    imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($im, 4, 3, 2, $text, $color);
    header('Content-type: image/png'); 
    imagepng($im);
    ?>
```

Затем я в другом файле, content.php прописываю следующее

```
<img src="img.php"/>
```

Ничего не происходит, помогите пожалуйста. Картинка не выводится.

Comment: А что выводится в броузере если набрать URL: `http://site/path/to/img.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header ("Content-type: image/png");
```

Укажите в начале.

Comment: все у него указано, зачем второй раз писать это?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего причина ошибки в неправильности путей до файла здесь

```
<img src="img.php"/>
```

другого просто нет, должно работать по идее